# Selenium Webdriver:- Which classes implement Alert interface? How to call the methods in Alert interface?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, interface

We have Alert interface in selenium 2.0 API. Do we have any classes that implement Alert interface?
When we call driver.switchTo.alert().accept() or driver.switchTo.alert().dismiss(), how are these methods invoked? I do not any classes that implement Alert interface.

Please help me to understand this concept.

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code `driver.switchTo().alert()` returns an object of class `RemoteAlert` which implements the `Alert` interface. The `RemoteAlert` is a private class inside the `RemoteWebDriver` class.

Check out the [RemoteWebDriver code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java).

Comment: Thank you so much more the information. It really helps.